# com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active! Do not see any overflow issue

Tags: java

WE are using Hazelcast 3.5 and after running for 1 month we suddenly got this below exception. We are just storing the object into IMap and when the request comes, we pull the object from this IMap and uses them.

Thing is we do a web service call where the objects gets updated/pulled from another server based on an event. Suddenly when we tried to invoke the object manually thorough a program and placed into Imap, we are no more seeing this error.

We are not very sure about this behaviour why this has had happenly suddenly. When we checked the log, we did not find any out of memory issue or any other errors.  Unless we understand this, we do not know when this kind of similar issue can happen.

Please advise on this.

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:380)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:235)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:207)
        at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.toData(ClientProxy.java:179)
        at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.get(ClientMapProxy.java:186)
```

Comment: Somehow the client decided it isn't active anymore. The big question remains: why. Like you already indicated OOME is one potential cause. Did you get this exception only once, or did you get it continuously?